# Eclipse - Install plugin by code

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, installation

Is there a way to install an Eclipse plug in by code?

I mean, are there any java instructions in Eclipse IDE which once I run them, I got my plug in installed into Eclipse, just like I have used an installation wizard?

Plug in can be a File object or a URL where to download a .jar or a .zip

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: The Eclipse p2 system is used for installs see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseP2Update/article.html

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F

Comment: The path suggested by @greg-449 seems to be right. I'll analyze it to find the solution to my problem and then I'll post it here
Thanks

Comment: @manetsus the part of code is what i'm looking for. Sorry, I forgot to put a question mark after the second sentence